# Jasmine SpyOn File Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, jasmine, filelist

I have an input of type 'file' that I am writing tests for. Specifically, I'm testing for uploads of disallowed mime types.

Essentially, this is what I have:

code:

```
var fileInput = $(input)
var myFile = fileInput.files[0]
if (myFile.type !== 'text/csv'){...}
```

test:

```
    spyOnProperty(fileInput, 'files', 'get').and.returnValue([{
        type: 'application/pdf',
    }]);
```

Error: files is not declared configurable in node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js (line 4810)

So 'files' is readonly, is there any other way to accomplish this test?

Answer (score 0):

You can spy on jQuery and return a mock `fileInput` object.

```
spyOn(window, '$').and.returnValue({
    files: [...]
})
```

Comment: Are you sure it's possible? I'm getting the following syntax error: Argument of type '"init"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"innerHeight" | "innerWidth" | "length" | "outerHeight" | "outerWidth" | "parent" | "blur" | "foc...'

Comment: You can try using the `window` object to mock `$` instead, I updated the answer.

Comment: Perhaps you can be a little more clear? [It works for me.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MVjJdP)